# module 'npyscreen' has no attribute 'wrapper_basic'

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, npyscreen

When I try to use a function of the npyscreen module it returns the error that the attribute can not be found. I do not understand why. Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong?

```
import npyscreen

def simple_function(*args):
    print("nothing")

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    npyscreen.wrapper_basic(simple_function)
```

Error message:

AttributeError: module 'npyscreen' has no attribute 'wrapper_basic'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I named my python file npyscreen.py which is the same as the module its name. FIXED by renaming it!